# Is there a way to have a method that is not in the superclass, have access to the superclass's instance variable?

Tags: java, inheritance

I have the variable 'ticking' and its initiated to be a value of '0'. It increases when there is movement or when a car turns to a different position. The Traffic class is suppose to be able to have access to the 'ticking' variable and determine when it is red light or green light. I have not been able to have ticking be accessible in Traffic class and I am not sure if 'extends' (inheritance) of Vehicle in Traffic class would be advisable. If I do inherit then I can have access to the variable through a 'getTicking' method. But for me it doesn't make sense to extend it in the Traffic class.

superclass:

```
public class Vehicle
{

    private String location;
    private double speed;
    private double weight;
    private double moving = 0;
    private double road = 5;
    private double ticking = 0;

    public Vehicle(String location, double speed, double weight)
    {
        this.location = location;
        this.speed = speed;
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    public String getLocation()
    {
        return location;
    }

    public void move()
    {
        if(moving == road)
        {
            System.out.println("Can't move any further.");
        }
        else
        {
            moving++;
            ticking++;
        }
    }

    public double moveQuantity()
    {
        return moving;
    }

    public void detectEnd()
    {
        if(moving == road)
        {
            System.out.println("You've reached the end of the road: " + moving + " miles");

        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("You have not reached the end of the road.");
        }
    }

    public void changeLocation(String location)
    {
        this.location = location;
        ticking++;
    }

    public double getTicking()
    {
        return ticking;
    }


}
```

A subclass:

```
public class Car extends Vehicle
{
    String color;
    String dir;

    public Car(String location, double speed, double weight, String color)
    {
        super(location, speed, weight);
        this.color = color;
    }

    public void direction(String dir)
    {
        this.dir = dir;
    }


    public boolean canCarMove()
    {
        if(super.getLocation() == dir)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }

    }



}
```

A class:

```
public class Traffic
{
    private double time;

    public Traffic(double time)
    {
        this.time = time;
    }

    public double ticking()
    {
        
    }
}
```

Driver:

```
public class Driver
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        Car obj = new Car("North", 25 , 125, "blue");

        obj.direction("South");
        System.out.println(obj.canCarMove());

        obj.direction("North");
        System.out.println(obj.canCarMove());

        obj.move();
        obj.move();

        System.out.println(obj.moveQuantity());

        obj.move();
        obj.move();
        obj.move();
        obj.move();
        obj.detectEnd();


    }


}
```

Comment: You either extend Vehicle, or you pass the variable in order to access the ticking field.

Comment: I did not know variables can be 'extended'. I thought it was a class to class 'extend'

Comment: Updated my comments. There was a error

Comment: I know how extend would look like. I don't know how 'passing the variable' would look like. Are maybe saying that in the 'Driver' class, I can pass the ticking variable onto the method 'ticking' of the Traffic class ?

Comment: Are you sure you want each vehicle to have its own `ticking` value, or should that be a single counter for the entire program?

Comment: Single counter for the entire program. Vehicle is the superclass from which 'Car', 'Bus', 'Truck' inherit, so everything goes through it.